# How can I find duplicate words in a text file?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, duplicates

```
file_str = input("Enter poem: ")
my_file = open(file_str, "r")
words = file_str.split(',' or ';')
```

I have a file on my computer that contains a really long poem, and I want to see if there are any words that are duplicated per line (hence it being split by punctuation).

I have that much, and I don't want to use a module or Counter, I would prefer to use loops. Any ideas?

Comment: why would you not use counter? Counter is the right solution ...

Comment: When coding please don't every decide you just 'don't want to use' an actual solution. You're trying to solve the problem, don't just throw away a solution.

Comment: You want to check only line by line? or whole poem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets to track seen items and duplicates:

```
>>> words = 'the fox jumped over the lazy dog and over the bear'.split()
>>> seen = set()
>>> dups = set()
>>> for word in words:
        if word in seen:
            if word not in dups:
                print(word)
                dups.add(word)
        else:
            seen.add(word)


the
over
```

Comment: Sets are not the clearest solution, for example, line could start with 'Word' and ends with 'word'. These are not same for Python,and sets. But for us, these are same.

Comment: So that, your sets could have 'word' and 'Word'. but these are same things  for us, this is not the clearest solution

Comment: @JoranBeasley they are duplicate for US, not for Python. In your real life you actually says: 'Jack' and 'jack' are not the same words.?

Comment: yes they are distinctly different words in programming space  ... notice that the problem statement clearly makes no mention of case, when it is not mentioned one assumes that you are looking for case sensitive matches ... you explicitly state that you want case insensitive matches if that is part of the problem statement... the default interpretation is indeed that it is case sensitive

Comment: Don't get lost in made-up interpretations of what OP might possibly consider a distinct word.  Please focus on the substance of the question which is how to identify duplicates in a list using only loops and native objects.   How the OP wants to establish an equivalent class for words is an arbitrary choice and up to him or her (and irrelevant the the central question being asked).

Answer (score 0):

```
with open (r"specify the path of the file") as f:
    data =  f.read()
    if(set([i for i in data if f.count(f)>1])):
        print "Duplicates found"
    else:
        print "None"
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!!
I can give the explanation with working program

file content of sam.txt

> sam.txt
>
> Hello this is star hello the data are Hello so you can move to the
> hello

```
file_content = []
resultant_list = []
repeated_element_list = []
with open(file="sam.txt", mode="r") as file_obj:
  file_content = file_obj.readlines()
  
print("\n debug the file content ",file_content)

for line in file_content:
  temp = line.strip('\n').split(" ")    # This will strip('\n') and split the line with spaces and stored as list
  for _ in temp:
    resultant_list.append(_)
  
print("\n debug resultant_list",resultant_list)

#Now this is the main for loop to check the string with the adjacent string
for ii in range(0, len(resultant_list)):
  # is_repeated will check the element count is greater than 1. If so it will proceed with identifying duplicate logic
  is_repeated = resultant_list.count(resultant_list[ii])
  if is_repeated > 1:
    if ii not in repeated_element_list:
      for2count = ii + 1
      #This for loop for shifting the iterator to the adjacent string
      for jj in range(for2count, len(resultant_list)):
        if resultant_list[ii] == resultant_list[jj]:
          repeated_element_list.append(resultant_list[ii])
          
print("The repeated strings are {}\n and total counts {}".format(repeated_element_list, len(repeated_element_list)))
```

**Output:**

```
debug the file content  ['Hello this is abdul hello\n', 'the data are Hello so you can move to the hello']

 debug resultant_list ['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'abdul', 'hello', 'the', 'data', 'are', 'Hello', 'so', 'you', 'can', 'move', 'to', 'the', 'hello']

The repeated strings are ['Hello', 'hello', 'the']
 and total counts 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
def Counter(text):
   d = {}
   for word in text.split():
       d[word]  = d.get(word,0) + 1
   return d
```

there is loops :/

to split on punctionation just us

```
matches = re.split("[!.?]",my_corpus)
for match in matches:
    print Counter(match)
```

Comment: How about `collections.Counter`?

Comment: lol he explicitly states he doesnt want it ... so here is a custom implementation :P ... but yes that is the right answer imho

Answer (score -1):

For this kinda file;

```
A hearth came to us from your hearth
foreign hairs with hearth are same are hairs
```

This will check `whole` poem;

```
lst = []
with open ("coz.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split(): #splited by gaps (space)
            if word not in lst:
                lst.append(word)
            else:
                print (word)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
hearth
hearth
are
hairs
>>>
```

As you see there are two `hearth` here,  because in whole poem there are 3 `hearth`.

For check line by line;

```
lst = []
lst2 = []
with open ("coz.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            lst2.append(word)
            for x in lst2:
                if x not in lst:
                    lst.append(x)
                    lst2.remove(x)
print (set(lst2))

>>> 
{'hearth', 'are', 'hairs'}
>>>
```

Comment: Using a linear list search is almost never a good recommendation when you can use an O(1) hash table search with a dict or set instead.