# Check duplicate words from text file using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to check duplicate words from text file in python and my text file has the format like this, how can I check for duplicate words?
Text file example:

```
email | birthday | phone number
email | birthday | phone number
email | birthday | phone number
```

Comment: Pl check answers on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489728/how-can-i-find-duplicate-words-in-a-text-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find duplicate words in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489728/how-can-i-find-duplicate-words-in-a-text-file)